# Docker wordpress behind proxy generates 503

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx

I tried to setup docker with multiple wordpress-sites behind a nginx-proxy. So I tried various instructions, but none worked.

This is one of them:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx-web:
    image: nginx
    labels:
        com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy: "true"
    container_name: nginx-web
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./data/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./data/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - ./data/nginx/htpasswd:/etc/nginx/htpasswd:ro
    depends_on:
      - new-site-wordpress

  nginx-gen:
    image: jwilder/docker-gen
    command: -notify-sighup nginx-web -watch -wait 5s:30s /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    container_name: nginx-gen
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./data/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./data/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - ./data/nginx/htpasswd:/etc/nginx/htpasswd:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./data/nginx.tmpl:/etc/docker-gen/templates:ro

  nginx-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-letsencrypt
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./data/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./data/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    environment:
      NGINX_DOCKER_GEN_CONTAINER: nginx-gen
      NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER: nginx-web
   
  new-site-db:
    container_name: demo-db
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
       - ./data/db/demo:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: demo_wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress_password

  new-site-wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - new-site-db
    container_name: demo-wp
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/wp/demo:/var/www/html
      - ./conf.d/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: demo-db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: demo_wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress_user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress_password
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wp_
      VIRTUAL_HOST: demo.servles.de
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: demo.servles.de
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: louis@servles.de
   wpcli:
    image: tatemz/wp-cli
    volumes:
      - ./data/wp/demo:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - new-site-db
    entrypoint: wp

networks:
    default:
       external:
         name: test-network
```

All containers are created and work.
A wget to the IP of the demo-wp-container brings the correct index file.

But when the domain is called, only "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
nginx/1.19.1"

What am I doing wrong? Or does someone have a working Compose-file?

Look forward to the support.

Comment: Does `docker-compose logs -f` show anything useful?

Comment: There was a problem with the dns-provider. So now the site is reachable.